# Solving $f'' = \ln(f)f+(f')^2/f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve: $$f'' = \ln(f)f+\frac{(f')^2}{f}.$$ 
I was studying logarithmic and multiplicative derivatives and I need to know which function has the property that its 2nd multiplicative is equal to itself. One solution is $e^{e^x}$ but that is only because the multiplicative derivative of $e^{e^x}$ is itself so of course, the second derivative is itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd start by getting $\ln$ out of the equation, substituting $f=e^g$. Then you have $$e^g(g''+g'^2)=ge^g+(e^gg')^2/e^g$$

You can divide out the $e^g$ to get $$g''+g'^2=g+g'^2$$ so you are really trying to solve $$g''=g$$

This second order linear equation is known to have general solution $c_0e^x+c_1e^{-x}$. So your $f$ is $$f(x)=e^{c_0e^x+c_1e^{-x}}=\left(e^{e^x}\right)^{c_0}\left(e^{e^{-x}}\right)^{c_1}$$ The one solution you observed comes from $c=1$, $c_1=0$.

Comment: Thank you. I know now the general solution for equal nth derivatives, really helpful!

Comment: OK. I am unsure if I answered your question. Did you need to know how to solve $g''=g$?

Comment: No, im fine with that. Thanks, I didn't see the substitution of $e^g$

Comment: Gorgeous approach!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Another approach

$f'' = \ln(f)f+\dfrac{f'^2}{f}$ implies that $\dfrac{ff''-f'^2}{f^2}=\ln f$ or $\left(\dfrac{f'}{f}\right)'=\ln f$ so $f'=f(f\ln f-f+C_1)$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $u =\ln f$  to get a second order differential equation
$$f'' = \ln(f)f+(f')^2/f$$
$$\dfrac {ff''-f'^2}{f^2}=\ln f$$
$$\left (\dfrac {f'}{f}\right)'=\ln f$$
$$(\ln f)''=\ln f$$

Therefore:

$$u''-u=0$$